# SQL Query to display all products, total sales on 01-JUL-11 and 02-JUL-11 adjacent to each other?

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'Orders' as follows:

```
Order_Day  Order_id   Product_id   Qty     Price  
01-JUL-11   01            P1        5        5  
01-JUL-11   02            P2        2        10  
01-JUL-11   03            P3        10       25  
01-JUL-11   04            P1        20       5  
02-JUL-11   05            P3        5        25  
02-JUL-11   06            P4        6        20  
02-JUL-11   07            P1        2        5  
02-JUL-11   08            P5        1        50  
02-JUL-11   09            P6        2        50  
02-JUL-11   10            P2        4        10
```

Can anyone provide a SQL query to get the the desired Output as follows:

```
Product_Id       Sales on 01-JUL-11          Sales on 02-JUL-11  
P1                       125                       10  
P2                        20                       40  
P3                       250                      125  
P4                         0                      120  
P5                         0                       50  
P6                         0                      100
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It is simple `sum(qty*price) grouped by order_day , product_id` + pivot.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use MySQL `sum` with `if`

```
select Product_Id
SUM(IF(Order_Day = "01-JUL-11", qty*price, 0)) AS 'Sales on 01-JUL-11',
SUM(IF(Order_Day = "02-JUL-11", qty*price, 0)) AS 'Sales on 02-JUL-11'
From Orders
Group by product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT
    PRD_ID
    ,qty,price
    ,ORDER_DAY FROM ORDERS)
    PIVOT
    (sum(qty*price) total_sales
    FOR ORDER_DAY
    IN('01-JUL-2011','02-JUL-2011'))
    ORDER BY PRD_ID;